# vector <vector <double>> operator

Tags: c++

I want to modify a

```
vector <vector <double>>
```

declared in `main()` from another function.
I pass the pointer to the vector as a function parameter; unfortunately, as soon as I try to modify the vector I get a segmentation error.

Originally this was my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void function(vector <vector <double>> *result, int k){
    double r = 0.2;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        r = r*0.2;
        result[k][i].push_back(r);
    }
}

int main(){
    vector <vector <double>> result;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) function(&result, i);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++) cout << result[i][j] << " ";
        cout << " " << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation with "g++" went good but I got segmentation error when I ran the program.
I think the problem is in the use of the operator [] since I am applying it to a pointer, so I might need something like:

```
result->operator[](k)->operator[](i).push_back(r);
```

which I tried but unfortunately doesn't compile.

EDIT:
I was using "push_back()" on result[k][i] which is a double.

I modified:

```
result[k][i].push_back(r);
```

in:

```
res[k][i]=r;
```

but I still get a segmentation error :/

EDIT 2:
The problem was in the declaration of the vector of vectors; I didn't specify a size. It should look like:

```
vector <vector <double>> result(int size);
```

Comment: Please fix your code to actually compile. "`in main():` does not. A [mcve] is preferred.

Comment: In the function you do `res[k]`, but that only works if `k == 0`. Think a little bit about that, and remember what `res` really is...

Comment: Uhhh, why pass `std::vector` by pointer when you can pass it by reference to make it cleaner and fix the problem at the same time?

Comment: Sorry, the first code wasn't complete, I updated it!

Comment: `result` (in `main`) is empty, since you never add anything to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pass the vector by reference:

```
//                     -------------v
void function(vector<vector<double>>& res, int k){
    //some calculations
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        //calculations which give r (double) as result
        res[k].push_back(r);
    }
}
```

If you really want to pass it by pointer, then you have to dereference it:

```
void function(vector<vector<double>>* res, int k){
    //some calculations
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        //calculations which give r (double) as result
        (*res)[k].push_back(r);
    }
}
```

And as @gambinaattori says, you cannot push back into a `double`, you push back into the vector in the outermost vector.

You'll also need to first vector to be filled with vectors. If the first level of vector is empty, you cannot push back the second level since there is none.

Initializing the vector of vector with a bunct of empty vectors in it is done like that:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> result(5);
```

Now there is 5 empty vectors.

Then to pass by reference you need drop the `&` symbol from the arguments:

```
function(result, i);
```

[Here's a live example](https://godbolt.org/z/fyOavx).

Comment: I actually tried both versions but neither of them worked, the code is identical to yours; any suggestion? Thank you :)

Comment: @LucioPhys I provided a live example and more explanations.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! :D Now it works, I was missing the size in the declaration!

Answer (score 3):

In your example `res[k][i]` is a double, not a vector, so calling push_back on it screws you. Call `res[k].push_back(r)` instead or just write `res[k][i] = r`. Also, you may want to pass the vector by a reference instead of a pointer.

Comment: Inside `function()` `result[k][i]` is actually a `vector<double>&`, otherwise it wouldn't compile. `res[k]` dereferences the pointer (with `k=0` being the only valid value), and then `res[k][i]` retrieves one of the inner vectors.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understood where I messed up!